# Nginx with Codeigniter Controllers get 404 only the index page is loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I deployed an application built using CodeIgniter framework and the structure is
var/www/html/example
Versions used:
Ubuntu 22.04
php-fpm -8.1
nginx 1.18`enter code here`
CodeIgniter 3.1.13`enter code here`

Below is my configuration of example.com in sites-available folder

```
 server {
    #listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/example.com;

    autoindex on;
    index index.php`` index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
        

        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        #try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
         }    

         location @rewrites {
             if (!-e $request_filename)
            {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /application/index.php/$1 last;
                break;
            }
         }
    location ~* ^/(assets|files|robots\.txt) { }


    location = /favicon.ico {
        return 204;
        access_log     off;
        log_not_found  off;
    }

    location = /.env {
        return 204;
        access_log     off;
        log_not_found  off;
    }
        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
  error_page 404 /application/index.php;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on; 
    location ~ \.php$ {          
                
      fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO            $fastcgi_path_info;
          fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED      $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

          fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING         $query_string;
          fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD       $request_method;
          fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE         $content_type;
          fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH       $content_length;

          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME          $fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME      $request_filename;
          fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI          $request_uri;
          fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI         $document_uri;
          fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT        $document_root;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL      $server_protocol;

          fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE      nginx;

          fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR          $remote_addr;
          fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT          $remote_port;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR          $server_addr;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT          $server_port;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME          $server_name;

          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          #fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /application/index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

CI - config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Please lemme know what am I missing. Appreciate for the support in advance.